# To write dot product \cdot is not working

Tags: math-mode, equations, greek

I am trying to write the following equation:

[image]

But when I write this in the equation:

```
\documentclass[applsci,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex,10pt,a4paper]{Definitions/mdpi} 
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{\sigma+f^{b}}=0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

It gives me this:

[image]

This is not working for a specific class of file, a journal prescribed. I have used this similar expression elsewhere and it has worked.

Comment: What happens if you load the `bm` package and use `\bm` instead of `\marhbf`?

Comment: i can't reproduce your result. it works fine ... please extend your code snippet to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass ....` and ending with `\end{document}` which reproduce your result.

Comment: @Mico: This is a document class supplied by a journal, I am not sure I can add packages to this.  However, your suggestion works.  Will it be possible to do this without adding other packages?

Comment: @Zarko: I edited the code snippet, as per your suggestion.

Comment: BTW, this isn't a problem with `\cdot`, but with the font displaying `\sigma` (and $f$ and $b$ are also roman type, not math type).

Comment: The comment by @manooooh on the answer by @egreg seems correct. The `cls` file loads the `amsmath` package. Replacing `\mathbf` by `\boldsymbol` will produce what seems to be a suitably typeset equation. manooooh, perhaps you should write this as answer.

Comment: @Sauradeep - Both the `amsmath` and the `bm` packages are standard packages. I've never heard of a document class *not* allowing the loading of these packages.

Answer (score 6):

I have two suggestions:

- Load the `amsmath` package and rewrite the equation as

  ```
  \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma} + \mathbf{f}^{\mathbf{b}}=0
  ```
- Load the `bm` ("bold math") package and rewrite the equation as

  ```
  \nabla \cdot \bm{\sigma} + \bm{f^b}=0
  ```

The former method will generate upright-bold letters "f" and "b"; the second will generate italic-bold letters "f" and "b". Your choice.

[image]

Note that the `+` symbol should (almost certainly) *not* be rendered in **bold**. For sure, `\mathbf{\sigma}` is not good; write either `\boldsymbol{\sigma}` or `\bm{\sigma}`.

```
\documentclass[applsci,article,submit,moreauthors,
               pdftex,10pt,a4paper]{mdpi} % see https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\boldsymbol" macro
\usepackage{bm}      % for "\bm" macro

\makeatletter  % just to make the code minimally compilable
\let\@Title\relax
\let\@Author\relax
\let\@address\relax
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:boldsymb}
\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma} + \mathbf{f}^{\mathbf{b}}=0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:bm}
\nabla \cdot \bm{\sigma} + \bm{f^b}=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `\bm`, not `\mathbf`:

```
\documentclass[
  applsci,
  article,
  submit,
  moreauthors,
  10pt,
  a4paper,
]{Definitions/mdpi}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\Title{Title}
\Author{Author}
\address{x}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
\nabla \cdot \bm{\sigma}+\bm{f}^{\bm{b}}=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask why you didn't write `\boldsymbol`? I always use it... Should I leave and start using `\bm`?

Comment: @manooooh If you load `bm` after `amsmath`, `\bm` and `\boldsymbol` are synonyms; if you don't load `bm` you get less good results.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you. By "synonyms" do you mean that I can use both of them no matter the context? Then, you say "if you don't load `\bm` you get less good results": why only loading a package " is good"? Shouldn't I use `\bm` command? Because here's a topic where compares `\bm` vs. `\boldsymbol`, and the first one  won.

Comment: @manooooh `\boldsymbol` gives less good result in several cases, compared to `\bm` (which needs `\usepackage{bm}` *after* `amsmath`). Since the `bm` package does `\let\boldsymbol\bm`, you can use the two commands interchangeably (but `\bm` is admittedly shorter). The difference of course can only be seen if you don't load `bm` (and don't use `\bm`).